# Is it possible to return grouped rows in flask-alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get back rows that are grouped based on a certain column, but I'm not sure flask-sqlalchemy can return something like this. A simple example:

```
# Models
class User(Model):
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String, default="foobar")
  items = relationship("Item", backref="user", lazy="dynamic")

class Item(Model):
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String, default="")
   custom_name = Column(String, default="default")
   owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

An example data table would be:

```
# Users
id   name 
-------------
1    Bob
2    Alice

# Items
id    name    custom_name    owner_id
--------------------------------------
1     book1   reading_list   1
2     book2   reading_list   1
3     teapot  kitchen_thing  2
4     tv      entertainment  1
5     pc      entertainment  2
```

I would like all of `Bob`'s items, but grouped based on `custom_name`. The end result would be to display that data by their `custom_name` on a jinja2 template:

```
# Somewhere in flask
@app.route("/mylist")
def mylist():
    # get all items belong to Bob
    grouped_items = Item.query.filter_by(owner_id = 1 ).... # then chain the result to somehow group by custom_name ?

    return render_template("mylist.html", grouped_items=grouped_items)
```

Then I want to render it based on the `custom_name`:

```
<!-- mylist.html  ...in pseudocode!... -->

{% for group in grouped_items %}
    <span>Item Custom name: {{ group.custom_name }}</span>
    {% for item in group %}
        <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Which should end up being:

```
Item Custom name: reading_list
    book1
    book2
Item Custom name: entertainment
    tv
```

I know I can create my own dictionary with `custom_name` as the key and the value being the list of items with that custom name, but I'm wondering if this grouping possible to do directly from flask-sqlalchemy instead of manually looping through the query result to build the dict?